# Unlock sd card ubuntu touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, unlock, bq

[How to access SD-card within Aquaris E4.5 (Ubuntu edition)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/603508/how-to-access-sd-card-within-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition)

There is anyway to have the SD card unlocked permanently?
I dont wanna do that everytime
:/

Comment: I don't know if this works, but you can try to mount your Sd card in your home directory or link it there

Comment: I dont think so. I tried to modify fstab but at the restart system overwrite it. :/

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question - This may help you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/601354/mount-home-directory-from-sd-card-in-ubuntu-touch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comment before recommended linking your SDCard from your home directory. This is how it goes.

1. [SSH into your phone](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601910/ssh-ubuntu-touch/653595#653595) or open the terminal app. Stay in your home folder.
2. Find the mountpoint of your SD-Card: `ls /media/phablet/`. In my case `AC5D-91D7`
3. Create a symbolic link. You have to replace `AC5D-91D7` with the output of the command in step 2:
       `ln -s /media/phablet/AC5D-91D7 SDCard`

Now you can simply click on the SDCard folder in the File Manager App to see the contents of your SDCard.

Additional:

In case you want to keep your files on your SDCard rather than the internal storage you may consider (example for Music):

```
    rmdir Music
    ln -s /media/phablet/AC5D-91D7/Music Music
```

Your Music Folder is now located on the SDCard.

[image: SDCard accessible as a symbolic link and Music and Video replaced by symbolic links to the corresponding folders on the SDCard]

Comment: It doesn't work. If you tip in a Terminal you can see the symbolic link, but if you use file manager you cant see symbolic links from the SD card untill you unlock the SD card.

Comment: It is working fine for me on Ubuntu Touch 15.04 r4. I formatted the SDCard from my phone prior to using it though. Never unlocked anything or even open the file manager before - only to double check my answer is working.

Comment: Oups there is something different between i think you wanted to say and what you said XD
If i make any symbolic link which name isn’t from the beginning in the home directory like a folder named programs which is stored in the SD card it wont be shown until i unlock the SD card by other hand your last example with folder "Music" which is by defect in the home works perfectly.
I'm sorry, also for my bad english.

Comment: What Version of Ubuntu Touch are you using? I never had to unlock anything. There is not even an option to do so in the File Manager as I have seen on older screen shots.

Comment: 15.04 r24
http://askubuntu.com/questions/603508/how-to-access-sd-card-within-aquaris-e4-5-ubuntu-edition

There you can see a screen shot of unlock "full access"

Comment: Yes, but that post is from March. With the recent OTA Update ago it now looks like in the screen shot I just provided in the answer. Did you try formatting the SDCard from the External Drives App? That is what I did when I first inserted it.

Comment: I did when i  bought the phone. I dont think that the app had change since then...

Comment: If I were you I would try again. Lots of things may have changed since you bought your phone. Ubuntu Touch is still a child. It is growing fast and lots of things change as you grow...

Comment: I tried it rightnow, the result is the same as befrore.

Comment: It may be specific to the Aquaris 4.5, since I run on a Aquaris 5 HD. Sorry. I have used up all my mojo then. :(

Answer (score 0):

With BQ E4.5 and OTA-8 (as of beginning of Jan 2016), for music and pictures, I did not need to do anything to make use of the micro SD card.

Formatted it with the "External Drive" app, then put that card on a laptop, put some music on the Music folder of the card, put back the card on the phone and the music was found in the Music app.

For the camera, it now puts the new pictures on the SD card, there is an option to use the internal storage instead.

For these two things, camera photo and music, it seems to just work, no linking required, etc..